# iOS: NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest delayed operation on NSImageView

Tags: ios, http, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I am sending an asynchronous http GET request and the completionHandler is being called correctly. Code in the callback like NSLog gets run as I can see the output in the logs. However, the lines: self.imageView.image = nil; doesn't seem to go into effect until a few seconds after the NSLog statement "got here". Does anyone know what's happening? The sample code is below:

In ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

-void viewDidLoad {
    // ImageView
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.imageView.image = image;
}

-void test {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.imageView.image = nil;
        NSLog(@"got here");
    }];
}
```

@end

Comment: Try sending nil to the queue parameter to have the completionHandler execute on the main thread

Comment: I tried setting queue:nil, but that causes the NSURLConnection's completionHandler not get called.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, looks like setting the queue param to [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] fixed as it is here:

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: making multiple requests in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409211/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler-making-multiple)

Answer (score 3):

As Undept suggested, call thoses lines on main thread.  Like so:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (),  ^{
self.imageView2.image = nil;
self.imageView.image = nil;
});
```