# Read a plist from website

Tags: ios, objective-c, web, plist

I am incorporating an image gallery into my project. It currently reads from a local plist file, and I need to change it to read from a web server. I've read a number of ways to do this, but can't make it work in my context. This seems maddeningly simple. 
Below is my code:

```
NSString *plistPath = 
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *imagePaths = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

You can view  my plist [here](http://kpd.altervista.org/Images.plist)

This is what I've tried to no avail:

```
//get image URLs

NSURL *plistPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kpd.altervista.org/Images.plist"];
NSDictionary *imagePaths = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:plistPath];
```

I'd greatly appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Show what you have tried for reading the remote plist file.

Comment: Just output the plist file text as the html response body, using e.g. Php echo etc.

Comment: You are looking for the file in your bundle folder... So do you expect to run your app on a server or the server in your app? ;) You need to download the file first!

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409211/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler-making-multiple) ;)

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  What happens, is `imagePaths == nil`?

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, i just get a blank background when I compile. I haven't set imagePaths to nil.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this only works for `file://` URLs.  You'll have to load it from the server as if it was any other file from a web server.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, not quite sure how to do this, but you gave me a direction to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and it should be work :

```
NSURL *plistPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kpd.altervista.org/Images.plist"];
NSArray *imagePaths = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistPath];
NSLog(@"%@", imagePaths);
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provide serves a plist that contains an array.

Your code tries to read it as a dictionary.

Just change your code to read it as an array and you'll be one step closer.

But as others have said in the comments, you can't download a file (plist or otherwise) to your bundles directory. You have to download it to your Documents directory or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sincerely appreciated.